# how to store all created employees in an object

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor like this

```
function Employee(name, rank, mf)={
    this.name=name;
    this.rank=rank;
    this.mf=mf;
}
```

How can I create a new employee and storing the name, rank, and mf in an object with the ability to change it later on? Keep in mind i'm creating the new employee through a function so i can't just create a new var manually. THx.

This is how i create a new employee

```
function employee(){
var name=prompt("Last, First");
var rank=prompt("Rank");
var mf=prompt("M/F");
var ID=prompt("ID");
var confirming=confirm("ID: "+ID+"Name: "+name+"Rank: "+rank+", "+mf);
if(confirming){
    new Employee(name, rank, mf);
}else{
    console.log("Employee addition cancled")
}
}
```

Comment: What is that `=` doing there between the parenthesis and curly brace? To address your question: just reassign the variables... `var john = new Employee("john", "cashier", "foo"); john.rank = "manager";`

Comment: You are creating a new `Employee` object but you immediately throw it away (by not creating a reference to it)? Why?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/095bLrzL/

Comment: @prasad if i create a new Employee, how to i access it later? https://jsfiddle.net/095bLrzL/4/

(last line)

Comment: @eclipselzHere see the updated fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/Lfe0yaj7/ . Use like this `Employee('Allen', 'White')` not with `[] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your constructor code which can cause you compilation (syntax) error. Note the **equal =** sign. Should be 
`function Employee(name, rank, mf) {`

**Q:** How can I create a new employee and storing the name, rank, and mf in an object with the ability to change it later on?

**A:** You'll need to maintain a reference to that new object by storing it into a variable. You can achieve it by doing 
`var myEmployee1 = new Employee(...);`

So from there you could access that same object through calling the variable like `myEmployee.name`

If you are having a function to take on the create employee object role then you can either modify that function to, return the newly created object or populate straight into a global variable. My preference would be the former as it is much cleaner.

Also, tracking the employee objects in an array is 1 strategy you can use but depending on how many objects you are expected. Finding an object in an array may not be as efficient as storing them in a `{}` dictionary data structure. As you are required to loop through individual objects from an array before finding the right one, whereas dictionary you access objects straight from the key, essentially transversing a tree which is quicker in most scenario.

Obviously storing an employee object through using the name as the key can be dangerous because names are never unique. Instead you should be using the unique identifier `Id`.

Example:

```
function employee(){
    ...
    return new Employee(name, rank, mf);
}

var myDictionary = {};
var emp = employee();
myDictionary[emp.id] = emp; // Store the employee object by its key with value = the object itself.

// To access the very same employee object next time. Let say the id is 10 then you would do...
console.log(myDictionary[10].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain global array for object reference this check my sample code :

```
var objRef=[];
function employee(){
var name=prompt("Last, First");
var rank=prompt("Rank");
var mf=prompt("M/F");
var ID=prompt("ID");
var confirming=confirm("ID: "+ID+"Name: "+name+"Rank: "+rank+", "+mf);
if(confirming){
    objRef[name]=new Employee(name, rank, mf); //access using objRef['alen']
}else{
    console.log("Employee addition cancelled.")
}
}

//Your constructor. 
function Employee(name, rank, mf)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.rank=rank;
    this.mf=mf;
}
```

and you can access your object by simply objRef[name]. you can make id as key .